# Adding new columns to DataFrame Python. SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new column to a data frame. I have column of dates, I turn it into seconds-since-epoch and add that to a new column of the data frame

```
def addEpochTime(df):
    df[7] = np.NaN                         # Adding empty column. 
    for n in range(0, len(df)):            # Writing to empty column. 
        df[7][n] = df[0][n]  - 5           # Conduct some mathematical mutations...

addEpochTime(df)
```

What I've written above works, but I do get an error, i.e.:  SettingWithCopyWarning

**My question** is, how can I add a new column in a data frame and write data to it

I don't fully understand the way data frames are indexed, despite having read about the it in the pandas documentation.

Comment: You're performing [chain indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) which is why you get the warning, you should use the new indexing methods `loc`, `iloc` or `ix` to ensure you're working on a view rather than a copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say -

> I have column of dates, I turn it into seconds-since-epoch and add that to a new column of the data frame

If what you are actually doing is simple like - `df[7][n] = df[0][n] -5` , then you can simply use `series.apply` method to do the same thing, In your case -

```
def addEpochTime(df):
    df[7] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x-5)
```

`.apply` method accepts a function as the parameter , which is passed the value of each row and it should return the value after applying the logic.

You can also pass in a function that accepts the date as parameter and returns the seconds since epoch, to `.apply()` , which might be what you are looking for.

Example -

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [6]: df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x-5)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2 -4
1  3  4 -2
```

Comment: That's pretty nice. 
When using lambda as in this example, are you temp. storing the value of the data frame in x? and than executing the math equation?

Comment: No, think of lambda as just any function, `x` is the parameter to that function, the return value is what comes after `:` . `apply()` function internally does the rest of the work.

Comment: That's pretty nice. I'm Amazed that I no longer require a for loop.
But now when I try to "change to epoch" I get error: 
'Timestamp' does not support indexing

Code:  `allData[7] = allData[0].apply(lambda x: toEpoch(x)) 

def toEpoch(s):
     a=int(time.mktime(time.strptime(str(s[0]), dateParse(str(s[0]))))) - time.timezone
     return a
`

Comment: can you show what `allData` contains? , the input to `toEpoch()` , would be the value of `column 0` one by one , that is row by row. So are you sure you need to do `s[0]` ? Again, not the complete row from dataframe, just the value of `column 0`.

Comment: Try without the `s[0]` , just `s` .

Comment: `>>> print allData
                            0                       1         2         3         4         5  \
0     2014-08-26 05:30:00.000      0  0.253431  0.245299 -0.004066  0.141623

              6  
0      0.224971`

Comment: Try what I said , use `s` instead of `s[0]` .

Comment: It worked.....!Awesome, But that makes no sense to me though...? It seems by just writing `s` instead of `s[0]` I'm accessing the entire df....How does python know which column to access?

Comment: you already accessed the column before calling the `.apply()` method on it, notice that you call the apply function as - `df[0].apply` , which means apply it in 0th column of `df` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line and avoid the warning:

```
df
>>    a
   0  1
   1  2

df['b'] = df['a'] - 5
df
>>   a  b
  0  1 -4
  1  2 -3
```